Why are procedure parameters undefined in my Snowflake JavaScript stored procedure?
This is my stored procedure where I am trying to pass the database, table, role dynamically while calling the procedure but my procedure is throwing an error saying "Schema is not defined".
I think the values are not being read by the procedure at the point of execution, It would be helpful if anyone can assist me to understand the what's really wrong here, below is my procedure function code.
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DSAF.DATA_UNITY.grant_select_permissions(
    schema VARCHAR,
    catalog VARCHAR,
    role_name VARCHAR
)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$
try {
    var schema = schema;
    var catalog = catalog;
    var role_name = role_name;

    // Query to get table names matching the pattern
    var query = `
        SELECT table_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE table_schema = '${schema}'
          AND table_catalog = '${catalog}'
          AND table_name LIKE 'STAGING_TTD_%';
    `;

    var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({ sqlText: query });
    var resultSet = stmt.execute();

    // Iterate through the result set and grant permissions
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        var tableName = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
        var grantStatement = `
            GRANT SELECT ON TABLE ${catalog}.${schema}.${tableName}
            TO ROLE ${role_name};
        `;
        snowflake.execute({ sqlText: grantStatement });
    }

    return 'Permissions granted successfully.';
} catch (err) {
    return `Error: ${err.message}`;
}
$$;
CALL DSAF.DATA_UNITY.grant_select_permissions('DATA_UNITY', 'DSAF', 'REPORTING_ROLE');

I'm getting an error saying

Schema not defined

